# How to understand XACML Response?

Tags: xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I worked with the below policy and i am unable to understand the XACML Response. 
The policy which i am using is

```xml
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="TestPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0"> 
    <Target>
        <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"> 
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/> 
                </Match>
            </AllOf> 
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo2</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </Match>
            </AllOf> 
        </AnyOf>
    </Target> 
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of"> 
                    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue> 
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                    </Apply>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/> 
                </Apply>
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of"> 
                    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bob1</AttributeValue> 
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bob2</AttributeValue> 
                    </Apply> 
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/> 
                </Apply> 
            </Apply>
        </Condition> 
    </Rule> 
    <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule"/>
</Policy>
```

### XACML Request

```xml
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bob2</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">index.jsp</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Descendants</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

### XACML Response

```xml
    <Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo2</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo2</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo2</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

From this XACML Response i got four Result decisions as Permit ,

1. First Result decision is Permit and it means foo1 and foo2 resources can be READ by the user bob2 .
2. Second Result decision is Permit and it means foo2 resource can be READ and WRITE by the user bob2.
3. Third Result decision is Permit and it means foo1 resource can be READ and WRITE by the user bob2.
4. Fourth Result decision is Permit and it means foo1 and foo2 resources can be WRITE by the user bob2.
   This is how i understood from the XACML response.Do you think my understanding is correct ? If not Please guide me how to understand the XACML Response.

Comment: I guess, XACML request that you have given above is not providing above result, Could you please give the correct XACML request or just verify it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are trying the multiple decision profile with XACML 3.0. Yes you are correct. However,  your given XACML request is not the correct one to provide abovr result. Therefore it is great to update it. Normally,  when multiple decision profile is used, you can receive more than one results. As an example, you can as authorization for read and write actions for same request as you have done. Then XACML response contains two results. I guess you can fine more details about multiple decision profile from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/06/multiple-decision-profile-repeated-attribute-categories/)

Comment: Hi Asela, Thanks for your response.I edited the XACML Request.Please check it now once.